# Problema com acionar botão por id ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Boas estou aqui com um problema que e o seguinte eu tenho um `lop while` que me mostra todos os utilizadores e em cada um tem um botão seguir estou a fazer via ajax ao clicar em seguir mudar o texto para não seguir e a cor do botão e esta a funcionar só que quando clico em seguir ele coloca-me não seguir em todos que estão no while como posso resolver isto ?

Jquery

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".seguir_user").click(function() {
            var seguidores = {
               follower: $(this).closest('input#follower').val();
               followed: $(this).closest('input#followed').val();
            }
            $(this).addClass("seguir_user_click");
            $(this).text("A Seguir")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/processa_seguidores.php",
                data: seguidores,
                cache: true,
                success: function(seguidores){ 
                   $("#sucesso").html("sucesso").fadeIn(400);
                   $("#sucesso").fadeOut(4000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
$result_foodies=mysql_query("SELECT * from users_social order by id desc limit 9");
while($row_foodies=mysql_fetch_object($result_foodies)){
$result_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM posts where user_id='".$row_foodies->id."'") or
die(mysql_error());
$bar = mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
?> 
<form action="" id="seguidores" name="seguidores">
<input type="hidden" id="follower" name="follower" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="followed" name="followed" value="<?php echo $row_foodies->id;  ?>">
<div class="my_account user wow fadeInLeft">
    <figure>
        <a href="users/<?php echo $row_foodies->slug; ?>"><img style=" border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px;" src="<?php echo $row_foodies->user_foto; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    </figure>
    <div class="container_user" style="border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;">
        <p><?php echo utf8_encode(limita_caracteres($row_foodies->fb_nome, 13, false)); ?></p>
        <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:-15px; font-size:13px; color:#999;"><?php echo $bar['id']; ?> Opiniões</div> 
        <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:13px; color:#999;">0 Seguidores</div> 
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['FBID'] || $_SESSION['user_id']){
        ?>
           <div class="seguir_user" style="margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;">Seguir</div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Adicione também o seu HTML.

Comment: Já esta colocado

Comment: `$row_foodies->id` contém o id do usuário a ser seguido, certo?

Comment: sim contem o id

Comment: Acho que tinha entendido errado a sua pergunta. Seu código atual funciona e seu problema é somente o texto que está sendo alterado em todos os itens com a mesma classe?

Comment: sim esse e o problema e esta a inserir na base de dados todos que contém no while não adiciona só o que eu clico em seguir

Comment: Mude seu `$(".seguir_user").text("Não seguir");` para `$(this).text("Não seguir");`, tente isso e informe o resultado

Comment: Alterei e resolveu o problema do texto mas ele não me adiciona só o que cliquei em seguir adiciona todos que estão no while como posso resolver isso ?

Comment: Você pode adicionar um atributo data-id por exemplo em cada usuário, contendo seu id da base de dados; Ficando assim + ou - `<div class="seguir_user" data-id="1">Seguir</div>`, então você recupera na hora de passar o parâmetro por ajax assim: `followed: $(this).data('id')`, ah desculpe não vi que você já tem um input para isso... tente `$(this).closest('input#followed').val();`

Comment: Na div então coloco um campo id="id_user" certo ?

Comment: @CésarSousa Acabei de editar o comentário de uma olhadinha... vi agora seu input lá em cima com o id do usuário..., tente usar o que comentei e diga o resultado  `$(this).closest('input#followed').val();`

Comment: Tentei dessa forma mas agora o botão não faz nada actualizei o script acima para ver

Comment: @CésarSousa Fiz algumas modificações no seu código, por favor teste e avise do resultado obtido. Publiquei-a como resposta;

Comment: tentei dessa forma mas agora a pagina não me apresenta o conteúdo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21381/discussion-between-rafael-withoeft-and-cesar-sousa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tentei melhorar um pouco seu código fonte, simplificando algumas
>   sintaxes por exemplo `<?php echo ?>` para `<?= ?>` (PHP 5.4+), mudei a forma que
>   você estava usando os eventos de click, assim ficando mais dinâmico, editei
>   seu form para evitar forms com o mesmo nome e id; Por favor teste as
>   alterações e informe o resultado obtido para que possamos ajudar na
>   conclusão da sua dúvida.

```
<?php
$result_foodies = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_social ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9");
while ($row_foodies = mysql_fetch_object($result_foodies)) {
    $result_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM posts WHERE user_id=$row_foodies->id") or die(mysql_error());
    $bar = mysql_fetch_array($result_count);
    ?>
<form action="#" id="seguidores_<?= row_foodies->id?>" name="seguidores_<?=row_foodies->id?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="follower" name="follower" value="<?= $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="followed" name="followed" value="<?= $row_foodies->id; ?>">
    <div class="my_account user wow fadeInLeft">
        <figure>
            <a href="users/<?= $row_foodies->slug; ?>"><img style=" border-top-left-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px;" src="<?= $row_foodies->user_foto; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        </figure>
        <div class="container_user" style="border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;">
            <p><?php echo utf8_encode(limita_caracteres($row_foodies->fb_nome, 13, false)); ?></p>
            <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top:-15px; font-size:13px; color:#999;"><?= $bar['id']; ?> Opiniões</div>
            <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:13px; color:#999;">0 Seguidores</div>
            <?php
    if ($_SESSION['FBID'] || $_SESSION['user_id']) {
        ?>
        <a id="seguir_user" style="margin:0px 0px 15px 0px;" href="#">Seguir</a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document.body).on('click', '#seguir_user', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var seguidores = {
              follower: $(this).closest('form').find('input#follower').val(),
              followed: $(this).closest('form').find('input#followed').val()
          };
          $(this).addClass("seguir_user_click");
          $(this).text("A Seguir");
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax/processa_seguidores.php",
              data: seguidores,
              cache: true
          }).done(function( msg ) {
              $("#sucesso").html("sucesso").fadeIn(400);
              $("#sucesso").fadeOut(4000);
          });
      });
  });
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```